# Preg_match when string is sometimes a single word?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to pull a word out of an email subject line to use as a category for attached email.  Preg_match works great as long as it's not just a single word (which is what I'd like to do anyway). If there is only one word in the subject line, I just get an empty array.  I've tried to treat $matches as just a variable in that case, but that doesn't work either.  Can anyone tell me if preg_match will work on a single word, or what the better way to do this would be?

Thanks very much

Comment: Please provide the regular expression you are using.

Comment: Yes `preg_match` will work on a single word. Post your regex and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b`

The reason it wont match "word1" is because you included a word separator, the `\b`.

What you can do is just simply always inject the word separator:

```
preg_match("\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b", "." . $subject . ".", $matches);
```

Crude but effective.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` will work on a string one character long. I think that the issue here is probably your regex. My guess is that you're testing for whitespace and because it isn't finding any it says that there is no match.  Try appending `'^([^\s]*)$|'` to your regex and I wager it will start picking up those one word values. (`[^\s]` means give me anything which has no spaces in it, `|` means 'or'. By adding it to the front of your regex, it will include things without whitespace *or* whatever you already had)

Comment: Minor correction: `preg_match` will work on any string, even an empty string.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to post the regex I was using.   \b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b   And all I need to do is pull one out of half a dozen possible words from an email subject line.  Those words represent categories in an image album I'm working on.  I tried the bit of additional code mentioned above, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'll keep at it, but thanks for the quick replies!